# Pandas pivot_table percentile

Tags: python, pivot-table

I'm trying to describe columns A, B by mean, median, 25th percentile, 75th percentile, standard deviation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,9,3,4,6,8,2,7],
                   'B':[2,4,7,8,9,2,5,6],
                   'S':['L','L','L','S','L','S','S','L']})
```

Here is what I did and it worked since I only have 25th percentile:

```
df.pivot_table(columns = ['S'], values = ['A','B'], aggfunc = [np.mean, lambda x: np.percentile(x,25), np.median, np.std])
```

But if I also put the 75th percentile in, it gives me the error message:

```
Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Ideally I would like the output list the 75th percentile in the next columns.

Comment: As I commented on @SteveMisuta's answer -- the original error occurs because you have two lambda functions, each of which is given an implicit name of "lambda" in the output columns. The particular re-indexing needed for the pivot won't work with duplicate names. Simply renaming one or both of the lambda functions will solve it. You could also consider using `functools.partial` to curry arguments.

Comment: @Mr.F what do you mean by "simply renaming the lambda functions"? Do you mean replacing them? or naming them in a tuple like ('75th', lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75))? I tried the latter and didn't work for me. Is there some other way to "rename the lambda functions"? thanks.

Comment: In Python, a function object has a `__name__` attribute. Usually it is the function name that you choose (i.e. the thing following `def`). For a `lambda` there's obviously no name, so the name is just `<lambda>`. You can define one or both functions as either separate `lambda`s that are bound to a name, like `foo = lambda x:  ...` and then set `foo.__name__`, or else define the `lambda`s not as `lambda`s but as regular Python functions as in your answer, in which case their `__name__` will be set automatically.

Answer (score 6):

This will do what I think you want, but without a lambda and few extra lines:

```
def my25(g):
    return np.percentile(g, 25)

def my75(g):
    return np.percentile(g, 75)

df.pivot_table(columns = ['S'], values = ['A','B'], 
               aggfunc = [np.mean, my25, np.median, np.std, my75])

        mean      my25    median         std      my75     
S    L     S    L    S      L  S     L     S    L    S
A  5.2  4.67    3  3.0      6  4  3.19  3.06    7  6.0
B  5.6  5.00    4  3.5      6  5  2.70  3.00    7  6.5
```

EDIT: actually, it is possible to use only lambda functions if you use groupby to aggregate instead of pivot_table, and supply a name to each function.

```
func_lst = [('mean',np.mean), ('25',lambda x:np.percentile(x,0.25)), 
            ('med',np.median), ('std',np.std), ('75',lambda x:np.percentile(x,0.75))]
```

df.groupby('S').agg(func_lst).stack(level=0).unstack(level=0).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)

```
        mean      25    med         std      75     
S    L     S  L    S   L  S     L     S  L    S
A  5.2  4.67  3  3.0   6  4  3.19  3.06  7  6.0
B  5.6  5.00  4  3.5   6  5  2.70  3.00  7  6.5
```

I thought using func_lst in a pivot_table call might work but it doesn't. Anyway to me it is clearer to just define the my25, my75 functions and use the pivot_table.

Comment: You should add a comment to explain that renaming the function for the 75th percentile solves the problem. In the original case, the error occurs because there will be two columns with name "lambda" and the re-indexing operation needed to pivot won't work with duplicate names.